# Mockito: How to mock lambda callback? what is the type? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I have two class `TestTarget`, `MockTarget` and test code below. If the `TestTarget` has two functions with same name and same count of parameter, the `any()` is ambiguous. I need to assign the type to `any(ClassType)`. But what is the type of `() -> Unit`? I have tried `Function0` and it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Class TestTarget:

```
Class TestTarget(private val mockTarget: MockTarget) {
     fun testFunction() {
          // some logic to be tested.
          // call mockTarget.doSomething.
     }
}
```

Class MockTarget

```
Class MockTarget {
    fun doSomething(callback: () -> Unit) {
        // some logic here.
    }

    fun doSomething(listener: OtherType) {
        // Test code works without this function.
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
// setup mocks.

@Test
fun `verify testFunction`() {
    `when`(mockTarget.doSomething(any())).thenAnswer { invocation ->
        // callback here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `org.mockito.Mockito` with `org.mockito.kotlin.*`
and you can code like this

```
val anyLambda = any<() -> Unit>()
val anyListener = any<OtherType>()
```